# React- .map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

i have app built on node.js backend and react.js frontend. For code in react keeps throwing an error:

```
 import './App.css';
 import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
 import Axios from 'axios';
    
 function App() {
   const [material, setMaterial] = useState("");
   const [materialList, setMaterialList] = useState([])

   useEffect(()=> {
     Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/get').then((response)=>{
       setMaterialList(response.data);
     });
   }, []);
 
   return (  
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TEST</h1>

      <div className="form">
      <label>Search Data from DB</label>
      <input type="text" name="material" />
      
      {materialList.map((val)=>{
          return
           <h1>
             Material: {val.material}
          </h1>
        })
      }
      </div> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It still reports me an error that `materialList.map` is not function.

And I can't always figure out why.

EDIT:
Here is api section from backend part index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const sql = require("mssql");

const dbConfig = {

  server: 'host',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'database',
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
    encrypt: true,
    enableArithAbort: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,

  },

};
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.get('/api/get', (req,res)=>{
    var dbConn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    dbConn.connect().then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        request.query("Select TOP(10) * FROM [dbo].[Visual]").then(function (resp) {
            res.send(resp);
            dbConn.close();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dbConn.close();
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Hello Friend");
});
app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log("running on port 3001");
});
```

When I run the node.js server itself and give url / api / get it will show me correctly. But it is true that in recordset format. Maybe in this error?

Comment: do you need to parse your data to JSON? using `response.json()`?

Comment: unrelated notes: arrow functions automically return if you "point" to single statements, so `materialList.map((val) => <h1>...</h1>)` already does what you need, but remember that _you need_ to use `key` attributes. Never call `.map` without adding keys to the elements that yields (and, _never_ use array index as key).

Comment: but _on_ a related note: what happens if your reduce this to a [mcve]? Remove the axios code, do things are least run without an error now? If they do: put your axios code back, but _don't_ call setMaterialList, instead: console log `response.data`: is that even a value? Is it `undefined`? If it's not, is it an array at all? Some debugging on your part can be done here to actually find out _when_ you get that error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, you right. When i removed axios code - run without an errow. When i changed setMaterialList and instead console.log(response.data) so run without error but in console show warning with - 'Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return' and without expect result

Comment: No, your `useEffect` has no map code, so what does `console.log(response.data)` show you? Don't jump the gun, test each step properly: once you restore the axios fetching code, _remove_ the `setMaterialList` call so it does not kick in, only put in the console log so that _you_ can see what data you're getting back. Also, remove that `, []` at the end of your `useEffect` call. That second argument is for ["when React should rerender"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects). It either needs content, or it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Okey... after settingin useEffect only 'console.log(response.data)'. I am getting back 'response is not defined'

Comment: I guess what he meant was keep the Axios call and inside it log both console.log(response.data). Is it undefined or something other than an array? Do edit the question too, so it has the most updated details.

Comment: typically in axios the "data" prop on the response object is also an object, not an array (which is needed to use .map). Is there a particular part of the response object which is an array that you're looking for? What does your response object look like?

Comment: If you're getting `response is not defined` then it's time to consult the axios API docs, because then you're not actually getting _any_ data in that `.then(...)` handler.

Comment: Okej I will edit question. I add index.js from backend part.

Answer (score 0):

I've probably solved it already. My api comes with an MSSQL connection. And I used the wrong notation in the assignment. Because the result of my query is in the form of a recordset, I have to change the frontend, especially in the area around useEffect. I enclose the current state, which returns to me what I require. But if I am wrong that it is related to MSSQL and recordset, please correct me.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';


function App() {
  const[materialList, setMaterialList]= useState({recordset: [] });


 useEffect(()=> {
   const getMaterial=async()=>{
     const response = await Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get");
      setMaterialList(response.data);
   }
   getMaterial();
    
   }, []);
  
 
 
  return (  
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test</h1>

      <div className="form">
      <label>Search Data from DB</label>
      <input type="text" name="material" />
      

     {materialList.recordset.map(value=>{
       return <h1>Material ID: {value.MojeID}</h1>
      })}
      
      
      </div> 
    </div>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```